# Designing RESTful URLs for web pages

Tags: rest, web-applications, django-urls

Most REST tutorials arranged resources as following:

```
GET  /car/      -> list of cars
GET  /car/<id>/ -> info about specific car
POST /car/      -> create a new car
```

but when building web applications for use in browsers, there is a missing link that are rarely discussed, before you can POST to /car/, you need to GET a form for creating a new resource (car). What should the URL for this form be?

I typically used:

```
 GET  /car/new/ -> form for creating a new car
 POST /car/new/ -> redirect to /car/<id>/ if item is created else show form with invalid fields highlighted
```

but according to http://www.slideshare.net/Wombert/phpjp-urls-rest this is not a good REST URL. I can see why it's not a good REST, because "new" is really used as a verb and not a resource, but where should the form be then, because `GET /car/` is already used for listing cars, so you can't use `GET /car/` for the form for new cars.

In short, my question is: "What is the RESTful URL for 'create resource form'?"

On a slightly related note, even in a web service, it is sometimes not always wise to rely on the client knowing the schema in advance, therefore even in web services there could be a need to be a way for client to request the resource's current schema. AFAICS, this as a similar situation with the need to GET a create form (i.e. the form is sort of like a schema which describes how to construct POST query for creating the resource). Is my line of thought here correct?

Comment: Cannot upvote this enough! There's literally no mention of this missing link anywhere, and sadly no satisfying answer, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REST does not care too much about what your URI looks like as long as it identifies one unique resource and is self-describing. Meet those criteria, and beyond that, it is personal preference. Nothing prohibits using a verb in a URI if it makes sense to use one.

In regards to your slightly related note, what you hint at with the form being a schema is **media type**. RESTful architecture concerns the client and the server both understanding the media types used to represent the application state.

> A REST API should spend almost all of its descriptive effort in
>   defining the media type(s) used for representing resources and driving
>   application state, or in defining extended relation names and/or
>   hypertext-enabled mark-up for existing standard media types. Any
>   effort spent describing what methods to use on what URIs of interest
>   should be entirely defined within the scope of the processing rules
>   for a media type (and, in most cases, already defined by existing
>   media types).

Read more here: http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven

That is from Roy Fielding, the man who defined REST. In general, your media types should be extensible -- that is, any changes should add on and not break older clients unless necessary.

Comment: I guess what I want is an example of how other people have solved this issue (the need for GET creation form) in their RESTful URL. Another way I've used is to put the creation form on the /car/ page (which would be perfectly RESTful), but from usability perspective that's not always suitable if the /car/ page is already too crowded, for instance.

Comment: If you define a route of `/cars/:id`, and you try to have your form located at something like `/cars/new`, you cannot have a car with an id of 'new' -- something to be cautious of. Perhaps you could have something like `/forms/add-new-car`.

Answer (score 2):

I always assumed that "form" as such is not a resource, so `/<name>/new` is okay - forms are not usual elements of APIs. Author of the slides put that on a "bad" list, but didn't provide a correct one - I assume he was so RESTful that he forgot to think about such cases.

Comment: the issue is that `/<name>/new/` implies that `/<name>/new/` is a child resource `/<name>/`, while it is not since `/<name>/new/` is actually an action on `/<name>/`

Comment: I agree, but still - you provided the answer why it is bad (what I already know) and not the correct answer or other proposition. Can you give us new ideas?